# querySelectorAll invalid syntax

Tags: javascript, firefox, css-selectors, selectors-api

Try to execute this 2 code blocks in error console:

First one. Outputs NodeList.

```
var selector = "*[data-type=day][data-day='23']";
var a = document.querySelectorAll( selector );
alert( a );
```

Second one. Generates error.

```
var selector = "*[data-type=day][data-day=23]";
var a = document.querySelectorAll( selector );
alert( a );
```

Why `data-type=day` is ok syntax and `data-day=23` is not? Should attribute values always be wrapped as `data-type='day'`?

Here is the exception, which raises in second case:

> *[Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12"
>   nsresult: "0x8053000c (SyntaxError)" ]*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The browser is just following [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) which says:

> Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings.

and on [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they **cannot start with a digit**…

So `23` (which starts with a digit) must expressed as [a string](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings):

> Strings can either be written with double quotes or with single quotes

Comment: when why `data-type=day` is accepted? `var selector = "*[data-type=day]";` works correctly.

Comment: As it says, an identifier can contain letters and digits, but it can't start with a digit. That implies it can start with a letter.

Comment: @bhovhannes — Because `day` is a valid identifier